# unable to upload image using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

Please help me. This is my first project in php Codeigniter. Actually i am a Java developer.

I want to upload two image path  into my table and its image into my root folder eg uploads    I have many fields in the same table other then images. I am able to add/edit those fields from my form.(i implemented succussfully using codeigniter)

But currently I am facing problem in image upload. I don't know exactly how to upload  images using codeigniter. I tried to do it by myself since Two days but i could not solve my problem

*Error : I am not seeing any error. simply it inserts 0 values into my db table  as image path.
**I think the way i am try to upload image is not correct.***

myviews.php

```
 <? echo form_open_multipart('Booksetups/book'); ?>


                 <input type="file" name="img1" /> 
                 <input type="file" name="img2" />
               <?php          
                                               <br/>
                          <? echo  form_submit($submitbtn);   echo form_reset($resetbtn); ?>  
                 <? echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the error displayed ?

Comment: @mallix i updated my controller above please have a look. There are no errors displaying into my db with above code. it only insert a 0 value into my images columns

Comment: why do you set base url in this controller? Normally it is declared in config file in the application folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to remember is CI does not add `$_FILES` to the input object. You will need to access those like `$_FILES['img1']` etc.
So these:

```
'img1'=>$this->input->post('img1'),//image path is not inserting But all other fields are inserting into db 
'img2'=>$this->input->post('img2'),//image path is not inserting
```

should be something like:

```
'img1'=>$_FILES['img1']['name'],//image path is not inserting But all other fields are inserting into db 
'img2'=>$_FILES['img2']['name'],//image path is not inserting
```

depending on what you expect to be storing in the database. You can rename files, etc through the upload class. I would suggest reading over those [docs.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Secondly, you don't appear to be calling the actual upload method:

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

Not sure if you needed this but...
If you want multiple configs, you have to redefine the config for multiple files if you want them to have different paths...

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
$config['max_size'] = '1000'; 
$config['max_width'] = '1920'; 
$config['max_height'] = '1280';  
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload("img1");

$config['upload_path'] = 'some_other_dir/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
$config['max_size'] = '1000'; 
$config['max_width'] = '1920'; 
$config['max_height'] = '1280';  
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->do_upload("img2");
```

and if you don't want them to have different paths, you can just load in the library as you do in your example and call `do_upload()` with no params passed.

If i missed the point or you need more info let me know and I may update.

Comment: i did same as you explained but i have two problem now. (1) It is only inserting the image name with its extention into the db. I want to store its full path into my db.(eg. i want like /uploads/red.jpg  ! Now its storing only red.jpg)  (2). It is not validating the file type, i have mention only jpg/png/gif but it is storing all type of files . How to solve these 2 issues?

Comment: The file name thing is a matter of your own and not necessarily the upload class. You can just prepend the directory to the string: 'img1'=>'/uploads/'.$_FILES['img1']['name'] - file type, however, should be handled by the library. if $this->upload->display_errors() does not return any errors about file types, I would check the headers of the files and make sure their meme types are definitely what they appear to be. What kind of file passed the validation?

Comment: As you explained above, now i am able to save my full path into db. But still i have problem with validation. I am trying to show my error using `flashdata`  . i did like this :                                  `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        redirect(current_url());
    }` But into my view only Error Output is coming like saying `array` only. If possible Please update your answer with proper image validation & showing error in view using `flashdata`

Comment: How are you outputting the flashdata? You are passing it an array `$error` not a variable. So you will have to access it like it's an array. I suggest making another question.

Comment: you could also just die(print_r($error)) instead of setting flash data

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have use html in serverside. PHP doesn't know HTML but php. Client side or browser knows HTML.

```
<input type="file" name="img1" /> 
<input type="file" name="img2" />
```

Use suitable php method to generate html.

second thing, Your file upload parameter is different fromo codeigniter userguide

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

wrong file path may cause your otherproblems

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are not initializing the upload class library:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Also do you load the library:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

Comment: Please have a look into my above controller once more. i guess i have intializes the library. You could have given this answer as comment..