# how to upload image in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

i have trouble with uploading an image using codeigniter. i am new in this and didin't have a clue in how to upload image using codeigniter. so i hope any of you guys can help me out

this is my form named form_add.php

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/crud/insert"; ?       >">
    <table style="width:110%" class="table table-striped table table-bordered table table-hover">


            <td>Nama</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nama_produk"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Info</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="info_produk"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Harga</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="harga_produk"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stock</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="stock"/></td>
        </tr>


    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
        <tr>
            <td>Gambar</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="gambar_produk"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Di Buat Oleh</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="penulis_produk"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kategori</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="kategori"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kode Kategori</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="kode_kategori"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Simpan" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

and this is my controller named crud.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Crud extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

public function index(){
    $data = $this->mymodel->GetAll();

    $this->load->view('view_all_produk',array('data' => $data));

}

public function add_data(){
    $this->load->view('form_add');

}


public function insert(){
    $nama_produk = $_POST['nama_produk'];
    $info_produk = $_POST['info_produk'];
    $harga_produk = $_POST['harga_produk'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $penulis_produk = $_POST['penulis_produk'];
    $gambar_produk = $_FILES['gambar_produk']['name'];
    $gambar_tmp = $_FILES['gambar_produk']['tmp_name'];
    $kategori = $_POST['kategori'];
    $kode_kategori = $_POST['kode_kategori'];
    $data_insert = array(
        'nama_produk' => $nama_produk,
        'info_produk' => $info_produk,
        'harga_produk' => $harga_produk,
        'stock' => $stock,
        'penulis_produk' => $penulis_produk,
        'gambar_produk' => $gambar_produk,
        'kategori' => $kategori,
        'kode_kategori' => $kode_kategori
    );
    $res = $this->mymodel->insertData('produk',$data_insert);
    if($res >= 1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Tambah Data Sukses');
        redirect('crud/index');
    }else{
        echo "<h2>Insert Data Gagal!!!</h2>";

    }

    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 300;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('gambar_produk'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload-  >display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('form_add', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());


            }
    }
```

and this is the model named mymodel.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
public function GetAll($where="") {

    $data = $this->db->query('select * from produk '.$where);
    return $data -> result_array();


}

public function insertData($tableName,$data){
        $res = $this->db->insert($tableName,$data);
        return $res;

}

    public function updateData($tableName,$data,$where){
        $res = $this->db->update($tableName,$data,$where);
        return $res;

}
public function GetKategori($where=""){
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from kategori '.$where);
    return $data;
}
}
```

also this is what it shows after i run it

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: gambar_produk

Filename: controllers/crud.php

Line Number: 30

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\genstore\admin\application\controllers\crud.php
Line: 30
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\genstore\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

---

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: gambar_produk

Filename: controllers/crud.php

Line Number: 31

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\genstore\admin\application\controllers\crud.php
Line: 31
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\genstore\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

---

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'gambar_produk' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `produk` (`nama_produk`, `info_produk`, `harga_produk`, `stock`, `penulis_produk`, `gambar_produk`, `kategori`, `kode_kategori`) VALUES ('sada', 'asdas', 'asdasd', 'sdasd', 'sdasd', NULL, 'sadasd', '14')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/genstore/admin/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

so can anyone tell me what's my mistake? thanks

Comment: Look over to the right under **"Related"** >>>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to upload image using codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365639/unable-to-upload-image-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Also I recommend using codeigniter form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#loading-this-helper and the form_open_multipart() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multipart on the form?

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Edit: i see you are, there's a form within a form in your code!!

Comment: then where should i put the multipart?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html read the docs mate

Answer (score 0):

try this ! Send form-data encoded as "multipart/form-data":

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/crud/insert"; ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table style="width:110%" class="table table-striped table table-bordered table table-hover">
```

Comment: enctype is a FORM attribute